# Physical interpretation of the spectral function in a superconductor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity, many-body, greens-functions

Starting from the standard mean-field Hamiltonian of a superconductor,

$$H = \sum_{\mathbf{k},\sigma} \epsilon(k) \; c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}\sigma} c_{\mathbf{k}\sigma} + \Delta \sum_\mathbf{k} (c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}\uparrow} c^\dagger_{-\mathbf{k}\downarrow} + \text{h.c.}),\tag{1}$$

I get the following spectral function:

$$A(\omega) = -\frac{1}{\pi}\text{Im}[G_{ee}(\omega)]=
\begin{cases} 
      N_0\frac{|\omega|}{\sqrt{\omega^2+\Delta^2}} & \text{if} \quad |\omega|>\Delta, \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}, 
   \end{cases}\tag{2}$$

where $N_0$ is the density of states which I assumed constant during the calculation. This yields the following plot:
[image]

What is the physical interpretation of the divergence at $|\omega| = \Delta$?

How could we have deduced this behavior from the spectrum? (I imagine that we can do so because other features such as the energy gap or the particle hole symmetry are present in both plots).

I will appreciate any other comment which helps to understand the meaning of $A(\omega)$.

For completeness I add the plot of the energy spectrum, given by

$$\xi(k) = \sqrt{\epsilon(k)^2+\Delta^2}.\tag{3}$$
[image]

Comment: Those peaks reflect the fact that the energy states are very dense in correspondence to $\omega = \pm \Delta$. This happens because the dispersion relation becomes quite flat at those energies. In other words, there is a wide range of momenta having an energy in the intervals $\omega\in[\Delta,\Delta+d\varepsilon]$ or $\omega\in[-\Delta-d\varepsilon,-\Delta]$.